# Get frequencies of objects in an array using reduce and map

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, reduce

I'm trying to write a function which will take in an array and then return a map of the frequencies of each object in the array. For example, for the following array:

```
freqs([1, 2, 3, 7, 2, 7, 1, 2, 1])
```

it will return a map like the following:

```
Map {1 => 3, 2 => 3, 3 => 1, 7 => 2}
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
function freqs(items) {
    return items.reduce(function(prev, curr)
    {
        if (curr in prev)
        {
            prev[curr]++;
        }
        else
        {
            prev[curr]=1;
        }

        return prev.map();
    });

}
```

However, when I try to test it, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1' in 1

What is causing this? Also, is my logic correct? I feel like I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

1. If you don't provide an initial value to `reduce`, it will by default use the first element as the initial value. In your case, `prev` becomes `1`. Thats why you are getting this error. You should set the initial value to a `Map` object.
2. `prev.map()` - I have no clue what the intention is
3. When you do `prev[curr]`, you are using the `prev` as a normal JavaScript object. `Maps` don't have bracket notation to access their values.

---

Your fixed program would look like this

```
function freqs(items) {
  return items.reduce(function(prev, c) {
    if (prev.has(c)) {  // use `has` and `set` operations on Map objects
      prev.set(c, prev.get(c) + 1);
    } else {
      prev.set(c, 1);
    }
    return prev;    // return the map, so it will be prev for the next iteration
  }, new Map());    // Set the initial value to a new Map object
}

console.log(freqs([1, 2, 3, 7, 2, 7, 1, 2, 1]));
// Map { 1 => 3, 2 => 3, 3 => 1, 7 => 2 }
```

Comment: or simply `return prev.set(c, (prev.get(c) || 0) + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You are inconsistantly using `c` vs `curr` and `p` vs `prev`.
You are using [map](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) the wrong way.
Instead, just `return prev;`
Next up, you need to set a initial value for the `prev`-variable. This should be an empty object `{}` as a second argument for `reduce`. Do this, and you should be fine.

```
function freqs(items) {
    return items.reduce(function(prev, curr)
    {
        if (curr in prev)
        {
            prev[curr]++;
        }
        else
        {
            prev[curr]=1;
        }

        return prev;
    },{});

}
```

Comment: I fixed the variable discrepancies. And yes, your version works. Can you explain what I was doing wrong?

Comment: @FlameDra of course! I posted a link to an explanation on the `map()` function. It would take a functioin as property and apply it to every element of the array/obj and in the end return an array of the new values. You don't need this here. Just return the object `prev` itself instead.  
After the `function(prev, curr) {...}` I've added `{}` as an second parameter. This is the initial value of prev, cause you need an object first, before you can create `prev[curr]`. Hope this helps. Ask, if not.

Comment: @FlameDra But go with the solution of "thefourtheye" instead. It's better an really uses Maps. I only use objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to set property of object to value of array element, increment value for each matched element; `Object.keys()`, `Array.prototype.forEach()` to set value of `Map`

```js
var freq = (arr) =>  {
  var map = new Map();
  var obj = {};
  Object.keys(arr.reduce((obj, prop) => {
      return (prop in obj ? ++obj[prop] : (obj[prop] = 1)), obj
    }, obj)).forEach(el => map.set(el, obj[el]));
  return map
};

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 7, 2, 7, 1, 2, 1];

console.log(freq(arr));
```